# Building a dynamic Elasticsearch query using NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch v6 and NEST to search the advertisements that I create on my website.

This is my Document (from which I build the `Index`):

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "document")]
public class Document
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Text(Analyzer = "english")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public short AdDurationInDays { get; set; }

    public DateTime AdStartTime { get; set; }

    [Text(Analyzer = "english")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Text(Index = false)]   // Don't want to query this field
    public string MainPhoto { get; set; }

    public int ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    [Text(Analyzer = "english")]
    public string ParentCategoryName { get; set; }

    public GeoLocation GeoLocation { get; set; }
}
```

I have a created Elasticsearch client and I have a method called `SearchDocuments`. I want to pass a search term (keyword) and a list of Filters to this method. Search document needs to build a dynamic query based on the search term and filters which are passed in.

This is my search method:

```
public void SearchDocuments(KeywordMultiMatch Keyword, List<IQueryBuilder> filters)
{
    QueryContainer multiMatchQuery = Keyword.GetQuery();
    QueryContainer filterQuery = null;

    foreach (var filter in filters)
    {
        var query = filter.GetQuery();
        if (query != null)
        {
            filterQuery &= query;
        }
    }

    var res = Client.Search<Document>(new SearchRequest<Document>
    {
        Query = new BoolQuery
        {
            Must = new QueryContainer[] { multiMatchQuery },
            Filter = new QueryContainer[] { filterQuery }
        }
    });
}
```

In order to build my dynamic search query, I have created an interface called `IQueryBuilder`. This interface has one method called `GetQuery()`, which returns a `QueryContainer`.

```
public interface IQueryBuilder
{
    QueryContainer GetQuery();
}
```

Now my search term class (Keyword) and all the filters implement this interface, this is the `KeywordMultiMatch` class which returns a `MultiMatchQuery`:

```
public class KeywordMultiMatch : IQueryBuilder
{
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string keyword { get; set; }

    public QueryContainer GetQuery()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
        {
            var query = new MultiMatchQuery
            {
                Name = "Keyword Multimatch",
                Fields = Fields<Document>(p => p.Title).And<Document>(p => p.Description).And<Document>(p => p.ParentCategoryName).And<Document>(p => p.ParentCategoryName),
                Query = keyword,
                Fuzziness = Fuzziness.EditDistance(1)
            };
            return query;
        }

        return new MatchAllQuery();
    }
}
```

This is my `LocationFilter` class:

```
public class LocationFilter : IQueryBuilder
{
    public short Distance { get; set; }

    public GeoLocation GeoLocation { get; set; }

    public QueryContainer GetQuery()
    {
        if (GeoLocation != null && Distance > 0)
        {
            var query = new GeoDistanceQuery
            {
                Name = "Location Filter",
                Field = Field<Document>(p => p.GeoLocation),
                DistanceType = GeoDistanceType.Plane,   // plane is faster but less accurate than arc
                Location = GeoLocation,
                Distance = Distance.ToString() + "km"
            };
            return query;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is my `ParentCategoryFilter` class:

```
public class ParentCategoryFilter : IQueryBuilder
{
    public int ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

    public QueryContainer GetQuery()
    {
        if (ParentCategoryId > 0)
        {
            var query = new TermQuery
            {
                Name = "Parent Category Filter",
                Field = Field<Document>(p => p.ParentCategoryId),
                Value = ParentCategoryId
            };
            return query;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Abstracting the single purpose query builders was a good choice.

The arguments for `SearchDocuments` should be combined into a single model to simplify the method definition.

```
public class Query {
    public IQueryBuilder Must { get; set; }
    public List<IQueryBuilder> Filters { get; set; }
}
```

This should also allow greater flexibility when it comes to defining dynamic search queries as now it is not tightly coupled to the `KeywordMultiMatch` which in this case would be an implementation concern.

```
public void SearchDocuments(Query args) {
    var filterQuery = args.Filters
        .Select(buider => buider.GetQuery())
        .Where(container => container != null)
        .Aggregate((current, next) => current & next);

    var result = Client.Search<Document>(new SearchRequest<Document> {
        Query = new BoolQuery {
            Must = new QueryContainer[] { args.Must.GetQuery() },
            Filter = new QueryContainer[] { filterQuery }
        }
    });

    //...
}
```